# Doing arithmetic in AutoMapper and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, automapper

I am having some difficulty projecting my POCO object to a DTO object

My POCO object

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public LogEntry()
    {
        this.Username = Environment.UserName;
        this.LogNote = String.Empty;

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        this.LoginTime = now;
        this.LastSeenInput = now;
        this.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
    }

    public int LogEntryId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ConnectedFor { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan IdleFor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastSeenInput { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string LogNote { get; set; }
}
```

My DTO object

```
public sealed class ClientEventDTO
{
    public int LogEntryId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ConnectedFor { get; set; }
    public string LogNote { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan IdleForWithLast { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is I want `IdleForWithLast` to represent

```
public TimeSpan IdleForWithLast
{
    get
    {
        var tmp = IdleFor;
        if (LastSeenInput.HasValue)
            tmp = tmp.Add(DateTime.Now - LastSeenInput.Value);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

However when I do this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<LogEntry, ClientEventDTO>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.IdleFor, 
                   a => a.MapFrom(ent => ent.LastSeenInput == null ? 
                                            ent.IdleFor : 
                                            ent.IdleFor + (DateTime.Now - ent.LastSeenInput.Value)
                                 )
                  );

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    using (var ctx = new LoginHistoryContext())
    {
        var username = "Scott";

        var query = ctx.LogEntries.Where(entry => entry.Username == username).Project().To<ClientEventDTO>();
        var result = query.ToList();

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity

Changing `ent.IdleFor + (DateTime.Now - ent.LastSeenInput.Value)` to `ent.IdleFor.Add(DateTime.Now - ent.LastSeenInput.Value)` just gives me a different exception

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233067
>   Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Add(System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity

What is the correct way to do this kind of operation using while maintaining compatibility `QueryableExtensions`?

If you don't care about compatibility it can be easily done this way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<LogEntry, ClientEventDTO>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.IdleFor, opt=>opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    using (var ctx = new LoginHistoryContext())
    {
        var username = "Scott";

        var query = ctx.LogEntries.Where(entry => entry.Username == username);
        var result = Mapper.Map<List<ClientEventDTO>>(query.ToList());

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<LogEntry, TimeSpan>
{
    protected override TimeSpan ResolveCore(LogEntry source)
    {
        var tmp = source.IdleFor;
        if (source.LastSeenInput.HasValue)
            tmp = tmp.Add(DateTime.Now - source.LastSeenInput.Value);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

and that is the work around I will likely use for this situation, but I would like to know how to handle this in the future in case I am in a situation where I must use `QueryableExtensions` and I need to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore this member, and map it manually after mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<LogEntry, ClientEventDTO>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.IdleForWithLast, m => m.Ignore())
      .AfterMap((ent, dto) =>
           dto.IdleForWithLast = ent.LastSeenInput.HasValue ?
           ent.IdleFor + (DateTime.Now - ent.LastSeenInput.Value) : ent.IdleFor);
```

Or change default mapping in after map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<LogEntry, ClientEventDTO>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.IdleForWithLast, m => m.MapFrom(ent => ent.IdleFor))
      .AfterMap((ent, dto) => {
            if (ent.LastSeenInput.HasValue)
                dto.IdleForWithLast += DateTime.Now - ent.LastSeenInput.Value;
       });
```

Comment: It no longer throws the exception, but it is returning a TimeSpan of 0 for records that should have values. The `CustomResolver` method does return the correct values.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain works fine for me. Make sure you are using exactly same code as above. Your question had mixed if-else parts of ternary assignment

Comment: The 2nd version works, but I still can't get the first one to return values other than 0, I did a direct copy and paste.